# Creating array of multiple data-* values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple HTML elements with data-* attributes. I have a `name`, `latitude` and a `longitude` attribute. These attributes get their values from the CMS.

```
<span class="js-coordinates" data-name="{{ez_field_value(content, 'name')}}"
data-latitude="{{content.fields.address['ger-DE'].latitude}}"
data-longitude="{{content.fields.address['ger-DE'].longitude}}"></span>
```

Now i want to load the data values of each element into an array like this:

```
 var locations = [
     [name, longitude, latitude],
     [name, longitude, latitude],
     ...
 ];
```

I only get the `name`, `longitude` and `latitude` values from one element.
After this i can use the array values to create the markers on the google map.

Comment: Unclear what you want exactly. Please specify the question correctly. Is it the marker creation that is giving you trouble or the array?

Comment: Oh sorry i've edited it. The problem is to get the values into the array

Comment: Please share the code you currently use to generate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this function onto the document's ready event(JQuery) or window's onload event, to generate the markers:

```
function(){

    var tags= document.getElementsByClassName("js-coordinates");
    var locations = Array.from( tags ).map( x => {
         return [ x.dataset.name, x.dataset.latitude, x.dataset.longitude ];
    });


}
```